# Ошибка при запуске скрипта с pyarmor: Check license failed, Invalid input packet

Tags: python, android, лицензирование, обфускация, termux

Есть скрипт на питоне, я его обфуцировала с помощью `pyarmor` без лицензии, то есть чтобы он работал на любом устройстве без ограничений. При запуске получаю ошибку `Check license failed, Invalid input packet`, в [документации](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/v5.5.7/questions.html#check-license-failed-invalid-input-packet) написано, что эта ошибка связана с файлами `license.lic` или `pytransform.key`. Но у меня данных файлов вообще нету. `Python` версии 3.7.9, `pyarmor` последней версии, на ПК скрипт запускается без ошибок, ошибка возникает при запуске через `Termux` на `Android`.

**UPDATE:**

Сделала тестовый файл для Windows и для запуска на Andoid через Termux. Создала два архива: https://mega.dp.ua/ru/eKv5.

**Основной файл main.py:**

```
print('hello')
```

**В архивах находится 3 файла:**

`main.py` — обфуцированный скрипт.

`init.py` — содержание файла `__init__.py` в созданной папке `pytransform`.

`_pytransform` — `dll` для Windows и `.so` файл для Android.

**Содержание обфуцированного файла в двух вариантах:**

```
from init import pyarmor_runtime
pyarmor_runtime()
__pyarmor__(__name__, __file__, b'\x50\x59\..., 2)
```

Содержание файла `init.py` скопировано из `pytransform/__init__.py`.

**На Windows:**

```
>>> python main.py
hello
```

**На Android при запуске через Termux:**

```
~ $ cd downloads
~/downloads $ python main.py
Check license failed, Invalid input packet.
```

В документации при данной ошибке идёт речь об файлах `license.lic` или `pytransform.key`, но я не использую лицензию, следовательно данных файлов нету и на Windows запускается без них, так что видимо тут проблема в чем-то другом.

Comment: Было бы лучше, если бы вы добавили больше информации, таким образом будет легче (или вообще возможно) воспроизвести вашу проблему. Вам также стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Comment: @0dminnimda добавила.

Comment: https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/v5.5.7/usage.html#distributing-obfuscated-scripts

Comment: Вполне может быть, что эти файлы лежат где-то в вашем пользовательском каталоге. Я бы их поискал на компьютере под Windows просто даже поиском для начала.

Comment: @CrazyElf выполнила поиск на всём ПК, нет таких файлов: `pytransform.key` вообще нет, `license.lic` есть, но этот файл не относится к `pyarmor`.